# Is a locally free sheaf of finite rank finitely presented?

Tags: schemes, quasicoherent-sheaves

I need to prove that a locally free sheaf of finite rank is finitely presented. Being homework, I'm not asking for a proof but rather for an explanation of why my counterexample is wrong. 
Here is the counterexample

Fix a field $\mathbb{F} $ and the ring
 $$A=\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{F} $$

Consider $X=spec A$ and define a sheaf $\mathcal{F} $ to be $\mathbb{F} ^i$ when restricted to the ith copy of $spec \mathbb{F} $.

Now $\mathcal{F} $ is locally free of finite rank, but it is not even finitely generated as a sheaf.
In fact if we have
$$\mathcal{O} _X^n\longrightarrow \mathcal{F} \longrightarrow 0$$
Which is exact, it would be exact on the stalks, but if we choose a point $p$ in a copy $m>n$ and localize we would have
$$\mathbb{F} ^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{F} ^m\longrightarrow 0$$
Which can't be exact.

Comment: A sheaf of modules is finitely generated (resp. presented) if such an exact sequence exists locally, there is no requirement to find a global presentation as you tried.

Comment: That makes the question rather trivial (there are indeed subsequent points), unfortunately I missed some lesson and found the definition on the internet. Don't trust anyone on the internet, I suppose. Thanks for your help.